# Keydown event in angular-selectize?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, selectize.js

How can something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/DmLdh/3/) be implemented with [angular-selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize)?

I am having problems with listening for keypress events. The example uses `selectize.$control_input.on("keydown")`, but there doesn't seem to any such thing in angular-selectize.

Answer (score 0):

angular-selectize exposes the native Selectize instance in `onInitialize`:

```
        onInitialize: function(selectize)
        {
            $scope.selectize = selectize;
        }
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may also do it the via a plugin of selectize.

See the registration of the event at the end.

```js
/**
 * Plugin: "dropdown_header" (selectize.js)
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Brian Reavis & contributors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this
 * file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 */

Selectize.define('dropdown_header', function(options) {
 var self = this;

 options = $.extend({
  title         : 'Untitled',
  headerClass   : 'selectize-dropdown-header',
  titleRowClass : 'selectize-dropdown-header-title',
  labelClass    : 'selectize-dropdown-header-label',
  closeClass    : 'selectize-dropdown-header-close',

  html: function(data) {
   return (
    '<div class="' + data.headerClass + '">' +
     '<div class="' + data.titleRowClass + '">' +
      '<span class="' + data.labelClass + '">' + data.title + '</span>' +
      '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="' + data.closeClass + '">&times;</a>' +
     '</div>' +
    '</div>'
   );
  }
 }, options);

 self.setup = (function() {
  var original = self.setup;
  return function() {
   original.apply(self, arguments);
   self.$dropdown_header = $(options.html(options));
   self.$dropdown.prepend(self.$dropdown_header);

   this.$control.on('keydown', function(e) {
    //alert('A keypess $control!');
   });
   this.$wrapper.on('keydown', function(e) {
    //alert('A keypess $wrapper!');
   });
   this.$input.on('keydown', function(e) {
    alert('A keypess $input!');
   });
  };
 })();

});
```